# Copy initial field value to custom field in ETL scenario

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to copy a (temporary) email address to (permanent) backup field when the contact record is created by a rep. This should only happen when the contact is created. Later updates are irrelevant because the temporary field will be overwritten later on by an automatic ETL process.

```
trigger CopyEmailPoco on Student (after insert) {
    //Loop through all records in the Trigger.new collection
    for(Student s: Trigger.new){
        //Copy initial field value to backup field
        s.AltEmail = s.Email;
        // No need to update records, as changes to Trigger.new are
        // automatically saved in a "before insert/update" trigger.
    }
}
```

The trigger looks <strike>fine</strike> okay after I have bulkified it, or is there anything else wrong with it?
E.g. should I add some sort of error handling, etc?

It is often said, this sort of simple functionality should be accomplished [declaratively](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/12/forcedotcom-declarative-development.html). However, I think a trigger is the weapon of choice here, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should definitely consider "clicks-not-code" whenever possible. However, due to the fact that the Process Builder's engine tends to perform rather poorly on large updates, you might be better off simply using a Workflow Rule instead. Basically, the Workflow Rule says "when a record is created, copy the Email field to the Alternative Email field." No code at all, very easy to maintain... until you need something that involves code.

Triggers can execute twice as a result of workflow field updates, so if you plan on using triggers for other things, you have to consider the possibility that the workflow rule may effectively double your trigger's execution time. Should you plan on doing more work later, you might start off with a trigger, otherwise, simply go with the Workflow Rule. If you find strange things going on with your triggers later, remember to check your workflow rules and Process Builder to see if your triggers are executing more than once.

As far as your trigger is concerned, it's properly bulkified, but it is *not* properly written. In an "AFTER X" (insert or update) event, Trigger.new is effectively read-only. This means that the attempted field write on line 7 will result in a runtime error. Instead, you need to modify the record *before* it is committed to the database. You would do this with the "before insert" DML event instead.

Finally, as a matter of principle, you should eliminate all pointless logic. Since the trigger is written as "before insert" (after making the above suggested change), you should not be checking if the trigger execution context "isBefore" and "isInsert", because your trigger will only fire during a "before insert" event. Your trigger will not execute in an "after update" scenario, for example, because you have not told it to do so.

I realize you'll find a lot of examples where people do this, but really, you're just harming your execution time pointlessly. There are times when you need to check if you're in a before or after context, such as when you start implementing a trigger framework, but until you get to that point, there's no need to check things that are obvious.

As a super-simplistic example, imagine you wrote the following unit test:

```
@isTest static void testAdd1and1() {
  System.assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
}
```

What does this unit test prove? It proves that the rules of arithmetic have not changed. This test, were it in your code, would only serve to slow down deployment times when you run all tests. If this test ever failed, you wouldn't even be able to fix the problem, because clearly the issue lies in the system software. It serves no purpose.

Similarly, if you tell the system that it should only fire a trigger before insert, you don't really need to check if the trigger is in a before insert context. It *must* be, otherwise there is a bug with the platform. I find it a lot easier to simply trust that the system is not broken, and will generally perform in the way it is documented as behaving.

As such, the final trigger is really just five lines of code:

```
trigger StudentTrigger on Student (before insert) {
  for(Student s: Trigger.new) {
    s.AltEmail = s.Email;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This trigger is not looking fine. You didn't handle bulkification and update operation in a proper way.

Secondly if you have any other complex operations that cannot be handled through process builder or workflow then only go for trigger.

For this kind of functionality better to handle through click-not-to-code i.e. declarative way.